# How to start Locomotive server/app for integration testing?

Tags: should.js, locomotivejs, supertest

I am converting an Express app to Locomotive and I cannot figure out how to migrate my tests.

In Express, I simply did this in my `/test/test.api.organization.js` file:

```
var app = require("../app").app,
  request = require("supertest");
  should = require("should");

describe("Organization API", function() {
  it( "GET /api/v1/organizations should return status 200 and Content-Type: application/json.", function (done) {
    postReq.done( function () {
      request(app)
        .get( "/api/v1/organizations" )
        .set( "Authorization", authData )
        .expect( 200 )
        .expect( 'Content-Type', /application\/json/, done );
    });
  });
}
```

And that was it - simply `require`'ing the app file was enough. But Locomotive does not have an `app.js` or `server.js` file, the server is started simply from command line with `lcm server`.

How can I start the server/app and make my tests work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can boot the Locomotive app yourself:

```js
var locomotive = require('locomotive');

describe('Test Name', function() {
  before(function(done) {
    // instantiate locomotive app
    this.app = new locomotive.Locomotive();
    this.app.boot(ROOTDIRECTORY, ENVIRONMENT, function() {
      done();
    });
  });
  // your test cases
});
```

ROOT_DIRECTORY is the directory where your Locomotive project lives, ENVIRONMENT is the environment in which you want your Locomotive app to run (usually `test`).

Comment: I also realized that I need to use `app.express` for supertest instead of just `app`.

Comment: This doesn't work in Locomotive 0.4.1 since the boot() signiture appears to have changed to no longer include allow ```ROOTDIRECTORY```. The only way I've found is to export the server.js as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941736/ensuring-express-app-is-running-before-each-mocha-test